# Loan Calculation

Tags: calculus

Hello could someone tell me what I am missing? (Laughs)

A loan of £100,000 for 30 years, an interest rate of 7% (charged monthly) the monthly payments apparently are 665

I calculate 100,000 / 360 = 277.77.

277.77 + 7% is 297.21 not 665.

I just can't get my head around it.

I've used the pmt formula in excel and I know the monthly payments should be 665.

Someone please help me because it is seriously bugging me that I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interest is 7% per year, not 7% of the original amount for the whole 30 year loan.  If it was 7% of the whole amount paid just once, your answer of about \$297 would be correct.

That said, by my calculation the correct payment would be \$341.11, not \$665.